# Slow site with fast ping, why?

Tags: networking, ping, connection, http, network-traffic

Sometimes I'm using a Google service in a few browser tabs, and the Google pages all of a sudden start to load incredibly slow (dozens of seconds to start displaying the pages, such as Google results). A few minutes later, problem's gone (that happens at average, say, once a week or two). If I do a `ping google.com` during it, the response takes less than 20 or 50 ms (depending on time of day/amount of users in my area).

Why is `ping` fast, but sites are slow, during these strange moments? Shouldn't `ping` get slow as well, if that's a traffic problem?

If it's not a traffic problem, what else can it be?

PS: Asked first on [Network Engineering](https://networkengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/59011/slow-site-with-fast-ping-why), but probably off-topic there, I've been told.

Comment: Ping isn't a measure of bandwidth.  It sounds like your issue a bandwidth issue.

Comment: @Ramhound If it were bandwidth, the sites would have started to load, which is not the case.

Comment: 50 ms is less than 1/10 of a second.  Your issue isn't connected to high ping times.  The fact it took more than a few seconds to load a page is an indication of a bandwidth problem.  low ping times are not directly connected fast connections.  For example, traditional dial-up had relatively stable ping times, but low bandwidth

Comment: @Ramhound I understand that ping doesn't measure bandwidth. But if it was a bandwidth problem, the site would start to load, and take all the time (let's say 20 seconds) downloading each piece of the page -- and I would see each piece's name on Firefox status bar (downloading xxx from yyy.google.com, etc). However, all I see on Firefox status bar is "Waiting for Google...", which means nothing is being downloaded. It seems more like a communication problem, a handshake problem or something like that. I hope I made it clear now.